# Is there a way to get the (tomcat-)server plugin features of Exclipse in VS Code? (Autodeploy exploded WAR file etc..)

Tags: java, angularjs, tomcat, visual-studio-code

I want to switch my dev environment from Eclipse to VS Code. In Eclipse there is the Tomcat plugin which allows to add a project to the configured server:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/q98l4.png

I found a tomcat plugin for VS Code which to my understanding only works with complete WAR files.

I need the same hot reload functionality for my web app code (angularjs).

Any help towards a working solution is appreciated.

I've tried to use this [Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=adashen.vscode-tomcat). But I can't get it configured correctly to load the exploded WAR like Eclipse does it. (Have folders: libs,src & WEB-INF with the classes)

Comment: This is the opposite of what you're asking for, Fynn, but with the CodeMix plugin for Eclipse, you have access to VS Code tech and extensions inside Eclipse. I don't know your reasons for switching to VS Code, so can't say if CodeMix is the right "solution" for you, but with it you can keep using your existing Eclipse tech for Tomcat, and access VS Code features as well, without switching away from Eclipse.